# Is it possible to show GridLines only between rows that have data in ListView?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there a way to change the behavior of the `GridLines` property of `ListView` to hide the grid lines after the data? For example, if there's 10 rows worth of data, I only want to see 9 lines, only between rows that are actually filled with data. Otherwise `ListView` covers the entire control display with grid lines.

**EDIT**

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

This is what happens:
[image: what happens]

Comment: Try to add [mcve] with screenshot and see if you get answer faster.

Comment: ... + a screenshot/paint of the expected result.

Comment: added the requested pictures